# How to store cart items for users?

Tags: flutter, firebase-realtime-database, flutter-provider

I'm using streambuilder to fetch data from realtime database and provider for the cart methods,

the items stay in cart only if I sign out but dissapear if I exit the app or do a hot reload, how do I make each user keeps his cart items even if he closed the app?

How do I achieve this?
Do I change realtime database / provider and use Cloud Firestore Database collections or other databases like sqlite or using GetX instead of provider ?

list of items and cart methods:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

import 'package:plantel/screens/widgets/plants.dart';

class Cart extends ChangeNotifier {
  final List _IndoorItems = [
    [
      "Kalanchoe Tomentosa",
      'Easy to maintain, have furry leaves, have thick leaves',
      'assets/images/kalanchoe-tomentosa.png',
      '28',
    ],
    [
      'Anthurium',
      'Beautiful appearance, difficult to care, and poisonous',
      'assets/images/Anthurium.png',
      '25',
    ],
    [
      "Oxalis Triangularis",
      'Triangular leaves, photonastic response, toxic for pets',
      'assets/images/oxalis-triangularis.png',
      '33',
    ],
    [
      "Aloe Vera",
      'Very popular, easy to maintain, have health benefits',
      'assets/images/aloe-vera.png',
      '74',
    ],
    [
      "Clivia Miniata",
      'beautiful appearance, trumpet-shaped, easy to maintain',
      'assets/images/clivia-miniata.png',
      '32',
    ],
    [
      "Nertera Granadensis",
      'Visually unique, picky and light demands, difficult to maintain',
      'assets/images/nertera-granadensis.png',
      '31',
    ],
    [
      "Opuntia Microdasys",
      'Desert type,  bunny ears shaped, requires small amount of water',
      'assets/images/opuntia-microdasys.png',
      '29',
    ],
  ];
  get indoorItems => _IndoorItems;

  final List _OutdoorItems = [
    [
      "Cherry Blossom Tree",
      'A symbolic flower of the spring',
      'assets/images/cherry-blossom-tree.png',
      '114',
    ],
    [
      'Lavender',
      'Very popular, fragrant smell, and a beautiful appearance',
      'assets/images/lavender.png',
      '95',
    ],
    [
      "Jasmine",
      'Beatiful at night, fragrant smell, and very popular',
      'assets/images/jasmine.png',
      '83',
    ],
    [
      "Morning Glory",
      'Fast growing, trumpet-shaped, and mild fragrance',
      'assets/images/morning-glory-flower.png',
      '86',
    ],
    [
      "Maple Tree",
      'Deciduous trees often grown for the shade they produce',
      'assets/images/mapletree.png',
      '107',
    ],
    [
      "Rose",
      'Very beautiful,fragrant smell, and very sharp thorns',
      'assets/images/rose.png',
      '92',
    ],
    [
      "Hibiscus",
      'Many colors, fragrant,very beautiful',
      'assets/images/Hibiscus.png',
      '73',
    ],
  ];
  get outdoorItems => _OutdoorItems;

  final List _PotsNVasesItems = [
    [
      'Clay',
      'Good for growing plants, attractive, expensive and heavy in large sizes',
      'assets/images/clay-vase.png',
      '65',
    ],
    [
      "Glazed Ceramic",
      'Colorful, varied in style, good for plant growth',
      'assets/images/glazed-ceramic.png',
      '35',
    ],
    [
      "Fiberglass",
      'Classically styled, durable, lightweight',
      'assets/images/fiberglass-vase.png',
      '45',
    ],
    [
      "Whiskey Barrel",
      'Informal in style, verry affordable, becomes more fragile in time',
      'assets/images/whiskey-barrel.png',
      '9',
    ],
    [
      "Concrete",
      'Attractive, durable, and affordable',
      'assets/images/concrete-vase.png',
      '23',
    ],
    [
      "Plastic",
      'Lightweight, durable, and affordable',
      'assets/images/plastic-vase.png',
      '20',
    ],
    [
      "Metal",
      'Very ornamental, lasts very long, very thick',
      'assets/images/metal-pot.png',
      '42',
    ],
  ];

  get potsnvasesItems => _PotsNVasesItems;
  List _cartItems = [];

  get cartItems => _cartItems;
  void addPotsNVasesToCart(int index) {
    _cartItems.add(_PotsNVasesItems[index]);
    notifyListeners();
  }

  void addIndoorToCart(int index) {
    _cartItems.add(_IndoorItems[index]);
    notifyListeners();
  }

  void addOutdoorToCart(int index) {
    _cartItems.add(_OutdoorItems[index]);
    notifyListeners();
  }

  void removeItemFromCart(int index) {
    _cartItems.removeAt(index);
    notifyListeners();
  }

  String calculateTotal() {
    double totalPrice = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < _cartItems.length; i++) {
      totalPrice += double.parse(_cartItems[i][3]);
    }
    return totalPrice.toStringAsFixed(2);
  }
}
```

variables :

```
import 'package:firebase_database/firebase_database.dart';
import 'package:firebase_database/ui/firebase_animated_list.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:google_fonts/google_fonts.dart';

class Items {
  final String title;
  final String subtitle;
  final String price;
  final String imagePath;

  Items({
    required this.title,
    required this.imagePath,
    required this.price,
    required this.subtitle,
  });
}
```

this is one of the pages that use realtime database, the rest are the same,

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:google_fonts/google_fonts.dart';
import 'package:plantel/screens/widgets/cart.dart';
import 'package:plantel/screens/widgets/plants.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';
import 'package:firebase_database/firebase_database.dart';

class IndoorPlant extends StatefulWidget {
  const IndoorPlant({
    super.key,
  });
  @override
  State<IndoorPlant> createState() => _IndoorPlantState();
}

class _IndoorPlantState extends State<IndoorPlant> {
  Icon customIcon = const Icon(Icons.search);
  Widget customSearchBar = const Text('Indoor Plants');
  TextEditingController textController = TextEditingController();
  final ref = FirebaseDatabase.instance.ref('indoorplants');
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        backgroundColor: Colors.grey[200],
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: customSearchBar,
          foregroundColor: Colors.grey.shade200,
          shape: const RoundedRectangleBorder(
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
              bottomLeft: Radius.circular(25),
              bottomRight: Radius.circular(25),
            ),
          ),
          backgroundColor: const Color.fromARGB(255, 97, 122, 85),
          elevation: 0,
          actions: <Widget>[
            IconButton(
              color: Colors.grey.shade200,
              onPressed: () {
                setState(() {
                  if (customIcon.icon == Icons.search) {
                    customIcon = const Icon(Icons.cancel);
                    customSearchBar = ListTile(
                      leading: Icon(
                        Icons.search,
                        color: Colors.grey.shade200,
                        size: 28,
                      ),
                      title: TextField(
                        decoration: InputDecoration(
                          hintText: 'Search Plantel',
                          hintStyle: TextStyle(
                            color: Colors.grey.shade200,
                            fontSize: 18,
                            fontStyle: FontStyle.italic,
                          ),
                          border: InputBorder.none,
                        ),
                        style: TextStyle(
                          color: Colors.grey.shade200,
                        ),
                      ),
                    );
                  } else {
                    customIcon = const Icon(Icons.search);
                    customSearchBar = const Text('Indoor Plants');
                  }
                });
              },
              icon: customIcon,
            ),
          ],
        ),
        body: Container(
            child: StreamBuilder(
                stream: ref.onValue,
                builder: (context, AsyncSnapshot<DatabaseEvent> snapshot) {
                  if (!snapshot.hasData) {
                    return Center(
                      child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
                    );
                  } else {
                    Map<dynamic, dynamic> map =
                        snapshot.data!.snapshot.value as dynamic;
                    List<dynamic> list = [];
                    list.clear();
                    list = map.values.toList();
                    return ListView.builder(
                        padding: EdgeInsets.all(15),
                        itemCount: snapshot.data!.snapshot.children.length,
                        itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                          return Container(
                            decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                color: const Color.fromARGB(255, 218, 218, 218),
                                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20)),
                            margin: const EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 20),
                            child: ListTile(
                              contentPadding: EdgeInsets.all(20),
                              title: Text(
                                list[index]['title'],
                                style: GoogleFonts.anton(
                                    color: Colors.black, fontSize: 18),
                              ),
                              subtitle: Text(list[index]['subtitle'],
                                  style: GoogleFonts.ptSansNarrow(
                                      color: Colors.black, fontSize: 16)),
                              leading: Image.asset(list[index]['imagePath']),
                              trailing: Column(
                                children: [
                                  Wrap(
                                    spacing: 20,
                                    children: <Widget>[
                                      Icon(
                                        Icons.favorite,
                                        size: 30,
                                      ),
                                      InkWell(
                                        child: Icon(
                                          Icons.shopping_cart,
                                          size: 30,
                                        ),
                                        onTap: () {
                                          Provider.of<Cart>(context,
                                                  listen: false)
                                              .addIndoorToCart(index);
                                        },
                                      ),
                                    ],
                                  ),
                                  const SizedBox(
                                    height: 10,
                                  ),
                                  Text(
                                    list[index]['price'],
                                    style: const TextStyle(
                                        fontSize: 14,
                                        fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                                  ),
                                ],
                              ),
                            ),
                          );
                        });
                  }
                })));
  }
}
```

realtime database:

(https://i.stack.imgur.com/wdoNk.png)

Edit:
I've only linked the products with the list from realtime database and another list for the provider, and I have no idea how to write the code to save all users cart items if they closed the app and opened it again, how do I do that with realtime data base

Comment: You can certainly use a database of your choice to store data for a long as you like. Are you having a problem with that specific task? Please edit the question to be more clear what the problem is.

Comment: Yes, I've only linked the products with the list from realtime database and another list for the provider, and I have no idea how to write the code to save all users cart items if they closed the app and opened it again, how do I do that with realtime data base

Comment: Maybe this [resource](https://medium.com/firebase-tips-tricks/how-to-create-the-database-schemas-for-our-firebase-shopping-app-part-2-29f8bcac7acb) will help.